# Magento 2 - mage/url is not working in module. Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

Tags: magento2, checkout, url

I am running the Magento 2 on the localhost server. `http://127.0.0.1/magento3`
here I've built a custom module for payment gateway. 
In **custom JS I want to use the mage/url.**
I need to use ajax for the checkout process. Below is the code where I want to get use url.build.

But I get,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined in the console for console.log(url.build) ;

Also, I've got a function method where I want to use the ajax in Custom JS file at PATH
`app\code\vendor_name\module_name\view\frontend\web\js`

```
       "IOST",
       "jquery",
       "mage/url"], function ($,url) {
       console.log(url);
   });
   function transfer () {
       console.log(url.build);
   }
```

Button at this path with which i used to call the transfer() method.
`app\code\vendor_name\module_name\view\frontend\web\template\payment`
CODE

```
                     <span data-bind="i18n: 'Pay By IostPay'"></span> 
</button>
```

FILE:-
**requirejs-config.js** 
CODE:-

````
    map: {
        '*': {
            lazyloadScript:'vendorname_modulename/js/custom_func'
        }
    }
};```


Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance.
````

Comment: Where you call `transfer()` function?

Comment: On the same below the requirejs like i have mentioned in my code.
I can use jQuery, IOST in the transfer function, but why can't use the ur.build in requirejs itself or the transfer function.

Comment: you are using `url`  out of the define scope. check my answer.

Comment: add 'IOST' at last where you have defined

Comment: add whole code of `custom_func` js file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use below code in your `JS` file

```
require([
    "IOST",
    "jquery",
    "mage/url"
], function( iost, $, url ){

    console.log(url) ;
}); 
function transfer(){
    console.log(url.build) ;
}
```

**OR** you can use below code for your JS

```
require(
    ['uiComponent', 'jquery', 'mage/url', 'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento::js/iost.min'],
    function (uiComponent, $, url, iost) {
        "use strict";
        return uiComponent.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                console.log(url);
            },

            transfer: function(){
                console.log(url.build) ;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

After changing this you need to run below commands

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

You can follow this `JS` to understand how you can build URLs with the use of `urlBuilder` and how to use `mage/url` in your knockout JS.

> vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/web/js/action/gift-options.js

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: You need to pass 3 params here in this function **function( iost, $, url )** otherwise you can change order of IOST. Let me know if it will works for you then.

Comment: Please check my updated answer @Garry

Comment: This is the custom js file where i need to use transfer() function.

But after this above code. I get Error of mismatched `define([
    "jquery",
    "mage/url",
    "IOST"
],`.......

Comment: same error even after removing. 
`require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function( $, url ){
   console.log(url) ;
}`

Comment: Can you please update **requirejs-config.js**  file's content in your question if possible ?

Comment: Hi, 
Please check i have updated the **requirejs-config.js**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101005/discussion-between-kishan-savaliya-and-garry).

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Hi, Can i update this js in my custom JS?

Comment: You're getting same issue still @Garry ?

Comment: Yes, On Using your first eg.

`require([
    "IOST",
    "jquery",
    "mage/url"
], function( iost, $, url ){

    console.log(url) ;
}); 
function transfer(){
    console.log(url.build) ;
}`

Error `Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined`

Comment: Yes, Please update your code

Comment: Which Code shoud i update? I've tried both in the custom JS at this path.

`code\vendor_name\Module_name\view\frontend\web\js\ `

Comment: Yes, Please update this **code\vendor_name\Module_name\view\frontend\web\js** js file

Comment: I tried the second one. 
I get this error. :( 
`(index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: transfer is not defined`

Comment: Hi, please suggest me this
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296068/can-i-save-every-order-placed-with-custom-payment-method-to-order-status-complet

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below code because you are using `url` variable out of the scope of the `define` and one more thing if you have created custom payment method then you have to use `uiComponent` to extended the template 
you can check in this path.

> vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/checkmo-method.js

```
define([
    "IOST",
    "jquery",
    "mage/url"
], function(iost, $, url) {
    function transfer() {
        console.log(url.build);
    }

});
```

OR
As I mention above using `uiComponent` you can use below code also.

```
define(
[
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
    'jquery',
    'mage/url'
],
function(Component, $, url) {
    'use strict';
    return Component.extend({
        transfer: function() {
            console.log(url.build);
        },
    });
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This is my file at 
`vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/js/view/payment/method-renderer/checkmo-method.js`
`
`define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default',
  'jquery',
  'mage/url'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/payment/iostpay'
            },
   transfer: function() {
    
    console.log(url.build);
   
   },

        });
    }
);`

Comment: And when i trigger click on transfer. It says
`Uncaught ReferenceError: transfer is not defined`

Comment: update your question with html code. where you trigger click event

Comment: I got a button on placeOrder on checkout page.

Comment: update question with your code

Comment: updated please check