# Can i save every order placed with custom payment method to order status complete?

Tags: magento2, checkout, module, order-status, payment-gateway

I have integrated **Custom payment module**. I want to save every order placed with custom payment selected should be set to complete.

( If the **selected payment** mode is with **MYPay** ) **Order Status -> complete**

I have tried like this 
`vendor_name\module_name\etc\di.xml`

di.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" type="Iostpay\Iostpaymagento\Model\DefaultConfigProvider" />
     <type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="order_state_plugin"
                type="Iostpay\Iostpaymagento\Model\Plugin\OrderStatePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin**

```
vendor_name\module_name\Plugin\OrderStatePlugin.php
```

```
<?php

namespace vendor_name\module_name\Plugin;

class OrderStatePlugin
{
/**
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $result
 * @return mixed
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function afterSave(\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,$result)
 {
    if($result->getState() == Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {



    }
    return $result;

 }
```

But If this is the only way to do. what do I need to update in the plugin Code?

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want to complete that order then, you need to create Invoice and Shipment for current order first programmatically then after this order will complete automatically.

Comment: Can i set the order status to processing or complete by default?

Comment: Please check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/164600/magento-2-how-to-update-order-status-programmatically-in-custom-module?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: I went through this before, but can't find the way to do this. I mean what file should i code and what to code.

Comment: You can create observer event for that 'sales_order_place_after' and check if order placed through your payment method then you can change status of current order.

Comment: Okay, I have this observer now at 
**Path**
`vendor_name\module_name\Observer\Sales`
**OrderPlaceAfter.php**
`class OrderPlaceAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        //Your observer code
    }
}
`

Comment: could you please tell me how to update this observer???

Comment: Yes, checking that and give you some solution within some time

Comment: Okay, Thanks! I need to process / complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create one `events.xml` file here in your custom module

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

Content for this file is..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="set_processing_order_place_after" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Here we have used `checkout_submit_all_after` event so this will call when order successfully placed in Magento. So now we need to create one Observer file here

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/OrderPlaceAfter.php

Content for this file is..

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer){
        try {
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            if($order->getPayment()->getMethod() == 'iostpay'){
                $orderState = \Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING;
                $order->setState($orderState)->setStatus(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order::STATE_PROCESSING);
                $order->save();
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/OrderPlaceAfterException.log');
            $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
            $logger->addWriter($writer);
            $logger->info($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here I've changed Status of order from `pending` to `processing` after successfully placed order. You can change condition based on your requirement here. Also I've added one condition there, if Payment method is `iostpay` then only we will change order status otherwise not.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Let me know if it helps @Garry.

Comment: Great.. this helped.. Thanks.. 
One more thing what would be the **order status code for complete** order?

Comment: You can check list of order status const variable in this file **vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order.php** and for COMPLETE status you can use **STATE_COMPLETE**

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1 : as i have mentioned before you need to get current order status here using its API or MODEL by providing DI in the file
like e.g

```
 $order->getStatus();
```

SETP 2 : when you get the current status update status to what ever you want 
   like e.g

```
$order->setStatus('complete');
```

STEP 3 : now you have to save the order in order to save your current changing in your order e.g

```
$order->save();
```

Comment: Can i update it in this observer>>

`<?php
namespace vendor_name\module_name\Observer\Sales;class OrderPlaceAfter implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * Execute observer
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(
        \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
    ) {
        //Your observer code
    }
}
`

Comment: yes if the observer is working on order place after you can code it there as well

Comment: if you can get any task done by plugin as well as observer in my knowledge plugin is good practice

Comment: accept if answer helps